# Linux command to replace string in a filename (single)

Tags: linux

I have a following requirements:
1. I want to replace part of a filename using pattern.
Example:
Original Filename: ABC100.txt
Required File: ABCA0.txt
If you see here "100" in the filename was replaced by "A0". Here the pattern is last 3 digits of the filename

Please suggest a Linux command for the same.

Comment: See: https://linux.die.net/man/1/rename

Comment: When you are speaking about a pattern, do you want to rename multiple files? Could you [edit] your question to show other examples? And judging from the answers, do you want to _rename_ the file or just use the filename (in a script, for example)?

Comment: I need to replace filename one file at a time. Meaning, this command would be called at runtime once per filename.
However, this file may contain patterns like 100, 200 or 300.... and we need to replace them with A0, B0, C0...respectively.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `rename` command sounds like a perfect fit for you:

```
$ rename 100 A0 ABC100.txt
```

Comment: ...ok and if I have multiple patterns like
If filename contains 100 replace it to A0. contains 200 replace it to B0 likewise. How can I mention it in single command? Or do I need to write script?

Comment: @JitendraJeswani If an answer does not fully answer your question, you should not accept it as it means the question requires no more answers. Instead, [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/61479075/edit) to provide all details. Alternatively, you can [ask a new question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask).

Comment: @JitendraJeswani Using the `rename` comment with a code statement (`rename -E 's/100/A0/;s/200/B0/' *.txt`) will rename multiple patterns in multiple filenames

Answer (score 0):

I dont know if the filename is stored in a file or not. But try the following,

```
echo ABC000.txt | cut -f1 -d'.' | sed 's/...$/A0/'
```

Comment: Filename is not stored in the file contents.